# Scrolling down too fast in the Stack Exchange Android app gives an error

Tags: bug, android-app

To reproduce, in the feed or any list of questions (basically anywhere you can continually scroll down) scroll to the bottom so you get the loading icon. While it's still loading, try and scroll down again.

You'll get a popup saying "failed to load data." (it will still load correctly though).